# while scrolling animation to play only once

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

while scrolling the # logo and # navigation moves. I want to let the animation play only once but, how can I best implement?

```
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    var contentHeight = $('#content').height();
    var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();


    var newSize = viewportHeight - footerHeight + 50;

    var $navigation = $('#navigation');
    var $logo = $('#logo'); 
    var noRun = 0
    var $win = $(window).scroll(function() {
        $navigation.animate({
          top: newSize}, 1500, function() {
          $('#navigation .active').removeClass('active');
          $('#navigation .current').addClass('active');

          console.log('animation 1 finished');


          });
        $logo.animate({
          top: 100}, 1500, function() {
          console.log('animation 2 finished');


          });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the animation is played, unbind the scroll event listener from $(window) to make animation never be played again by the scroll event.

```
var $win = $(window).scroll(function() {

    $navigation.animate({
      top: newSize}, 1500, function() {
      $('#navigation .active').removeClass('active');
      $('#navigation .current').addClass('active');
      console.log('animation 1 finished');
      });

    $logo.animate({
      top: 100}, 1500, function() {
      console.log('animation 2 finished');
    });

    $(window).off('scroll');
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you are using jQuery version lower than 1.7, use `unbind` instead of `off`

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/XghCY/1/

```
<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>

$(window).scroll(function() {
    alert('scroll event is triggered!');
    $(window).off('scroll');
});
```